# PHP скрипт архивации

Tags: php, архивация

Ищу скрипт архивации на php. В принципе можно написать самому, но неохота изобретать велосипед. Требования следующие:

- учитывать таймаут вебсервера(скрипт не успеет отработать за 30 сек)
- целевая папка с файлами - более 15 гигов

Может кто-то сталкивался с проблемой?

P.S. Доступ к шеллу закрыт. У меня только php бекдор. Если бы у меня был доступ к консоли мне никакие скрипты были бы не нужны

Comment: Тупо чтение и запись на диск будут дольше 30 секунд.

Comment: gearman и фоновые операции ?

Comment: `system("tar -pczf /home/var/www/temp /home/var/www/folder/to/backup");`  
и да, 15 гигов не зажмешь за 30 секунд  
и второй вопрос: какого еще вебсервера? вы из вебсервера собираетесь запускать? оно у вас от переизбытка памяти умрет. Может лучше консоль?

Comment: Скрипт. Архивации. На. PHP. Пожалуйста.

Comment: Верно, не сожмешь. Поэтому он должен архивировать файлы частями. При следующем запуске архивирует уже другие файлы. В итоге получается несколько архивов

Comment: а `set_time_limit` работает?
по поводу "Скрипт. Архивации. На. PHP. Пожалуйста.":
[Вот. Просто. За. Гуглил.][1]


  [1]: http://bit.ly/1kqBSAc

Comment: "У меня только php бекдор" - это как понимать?

Comment: php бекдор -- действительно? Чем-то это напомнило виндовый бекдор (в прошлом -- Windows Backorifice -- "задний проход")

Comment: php бекдор означает что у меня доступ только по http. Я  могу залить скрипт и дернуть из браузера, но у меня нет шелла. И да, не поверите, но гуглить я умею. Что мне дают классы ZipArchive и им подобные? Я и так ими архивирую. Задача в том, чтобы прервать выполнение скрипта и продолжить далее с того места, где остановился до этого. Для этого нужно сохранить состояние итератора. Я смогу это сделать, но надо писать. Поэтому спрашиваю: Есть ли такие скрипты чтобы мне не писать свой велосипед?

Comment: @co11ter, словосочетание "php бекдор" означает взлом чьего-то сайта. Учитывая, что ftp-доступа у вас явно нет, вероятность того, что имелось в виду действительно это, взлетает до небес.

Comment: `set_time_limit()`?